# Postgresql: How can I set the id for null values following existed sequence id?

Tags: postgresql, sequence

I have a table with 10 million records, there are about 1 million records with id from 1-1 million, and about 9 million records with the null values. How can I set the id for null values with a sequence of id's that following the existing id.

Comment: Do you care about the order in which the other ids are assigned to the rows missing an id?

Comment: Will you insert new rows into that table in the future? Should they get ids from that sequence automatically as well?

Comment: Yes, I will insert a lot of rows into the table in feature

Comment: So how is the table defined? Are you using an identity column? Or an id column with a sequence as the default? How did the 9 million records end up not having an id?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this in a test area to see how long it takes to populate your table. We'll use a short example here.

```
create table test (id int, fullname text);
insert into test values (1, 'john');
insert into test values (2, 'john');
insert into test values (NULL, 'john');
insert into test values (NULL, 'john');
```

This simulation shows that records 1 and 2 have an ID and 3 and 4 don't have an ID, yet.

Create a sequence using which we will populate ID in records 3 and 4.

```
create sequence populate_test start 3;
```

Now, let's populate:

```
update test set id = nextval('populate_test') where id is null;
```

Result:

```
select * from test;
 id | fullname 
----+----------
  1 | john
  2 | john
  3 | john
  4 | john
```

In your case, you could try the `cache` option of create sequence like so: `create sequence populate_test start 3 cache 1000000;` to cache 1MM numbers at a time.